# RCT3 Chairlift Issue

Tags: rollercoaster-tycoon-3

I recently got back into playing Rollercoaster Tycoon 3 again. I built a beautiful chairlift that goes around my park, at a ridiculous cost, that took me a while to complete.

The chairlift has:

- 4 stations; each consisting of 9 station pieces
- 4 entrances and 4 exits; one for each of the stations

The issue: I only have 1 car...

WHY?

If anyone can help me with this, I'd be very appreciative.

**P.S. I CANNOT change the number of cars in the Vehicles tab for the chair lift as it is greyed out**

Comment: it's been years since I played RCT, but I remember there was a setting in the ride to fix this. something to do with the circuit mode (you don't want continuous circuit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Rapitor Thank you for the help, I looked into it again, I don't exactly know what I did, but I changed the ride from "Open" to "Test" and then I was able to change the number of cars in "Test" mode. I think for timing reasons you can't have the ride open while changing the number of cars.

Comment: This is correct - you have to close the ride in order to make ride setting changes like number of cars (or in rollercoaster examples, whether to use block sections or not_

Comment: :) ctwheels, when you return, you can accept your own answer.